# trying to use Python to read text files into Excel 2016 sheet

Tags: excel

Trying to use Python but struggling. I have several text files with similar content:

System id:  N-30
Measurement date:  17.01.17
Results file name:  71HJ1935.NMC
Measurement option:  MC Precision
Data source:  Shift register
Singles:       9493.060
Doubles:        770.560
Triples:         90.068
Scaler 1:          0.000
Scaler 2:          0.000

i want to do is read the files into one Excel spreadsheet that has headers and correspoding values under each header. Like so:

|**System id**|**Measurement Date**|**Results File Name**|**Singles**|**Doubles**|
|N-30         |   17.01.17         |  71HJ1935.NMC       |   9493.060|    770.560|
|N-30         |   18.02.18         |  82HJ2345.NMC       |   8546.456|    550.321|

I can create the headers in Excel i'm just struggling with read each files contents and sorting it into a Excel sheet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you struggle with parsing the text-files? Are they newline separated or completely mixed as it looks in the unformatted text you wrote?

Comment: Mixed.Texts and numbers

Comment: can you give an example in which you use a file from which you take the data and a final file in which you insert the data you would like?